# How to Unit test LiveDataMediator - Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, android-livedata

I have a mediatorLiveData

```
private val _userIsReady = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>()
val userIsReady: LiveData<Boolean> = _userIsReady.apply {
    val dataUpdate = {
        val userData = userDataResult.value?.userData
        val passwordData = passwordResult.value

        if (userData != null && passwordData != null) {
            _userIsReady.postValue(true)
        }
    }

    addSource(userDataResult) { dataUpdate() }
    addSource(passwordResult) { dataUpdate() }
}
```

So the question here is how to make dataUpdate triggers in unit test and make `userDataResult.value?.userData` and `passwordResult.value` not null. I in test I will be able to get inside if condition?

Answer (score 0):

You need an Observer attached to your LiveData in test to watch every change, without it no change will be observed.

Below a simplified example using MockK library:

```
// Mock class with MockK
val userIsReadyObserver = mockk<Observer<Boolean>>

// Add observer in setUp
userIsReady.observeForever(userIsReadyObserver)

// Remove observer in tearDown
userIsReady.removeObserver(userIsReadyObserver)

@Test
fun userIsReadyTest() {
   // do your stuffs to modify _userIsReady

   // MockK method to verify what happened
   verify {
       userIsReadyObserver.onChanged(true/false)
   }
}
```